# What's up with the fleur de lis on each post?

Tags: discussion, design

Each post has the following image:

http://cdn.sstatic.net/math/img/bg-question.png

[image]

Just curious what that's all about or if there's any significant meaning here. My understanding is that it is used to show a strong affiliation with the French monarchy.

Comment: My guess is that it just looks nice. (But that's exactly what I would say if I were trying to cover up our strong ties to the French monarchy.)

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Il sait! Tuez-le!

Comment: Secretly, it's because all of MSE pays homage to my [blog](http://mixedmath.wordpress.com/) ;p (which also has random fleur de lis)

Comment: This is a question for Jin, I believe...

Comment: From Wikipedia: Some modern usage of the fleur-de-lis reflects "the continuing presence of heraldry in everyday life", often intentionally, but also when users are not aware that they are "prolonging the life of centuries-old insignia and emblems".

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: I think you are just using the French monarchy as a cover for the [*real* secret society that is behind this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Scout_Association_1967-2003.svg)...

Comment: You might want to tag this question with [meta-tag:design], to draw the attention from Jin, who designed most of the SE sites.

Comment: Dear @Peter: congratulations for your syntax. Few French students of your age know that there is a hyphen between "tuez" and "le".  But I definitely do not condone your savage project for our friend Qiaochu's  fate :-)

Comment: I think more people would associate the symbol with the Scouting movement than with French monarchs. (Also, my impression is that heraldic fleurs-de-lis tend to be taller than they are wide, whereas the Scouting ones are usually lower -- as is the separator graphic here).

Comment: @HenningMakholm Scouting movement? What?

Comment: @Incognito: Um, [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fleur-de-lis_in_Scouting).

Comment: So, does this question have an answer? (I guess this is a bump)

Comment: I was just curious about this myself!

Comment: Alpha phi omega is my guess

Comment: But it has a really long list of affiliations including the Israeli secret service on wikipedia