# Meaning of the symbol under every question on MSE?

Tags: discussion, design

[image]
This symbol is under every question of math.se, both the main site and meta.
It'll even be under this question :)
Is there any meaning to it? I didn't notice similar "end of question" symbols at other SE sites. It's a silly question but I'm curious.

Comment: You aren't [the first to wonder about this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4055/11619).

Comment: Interesting discussion :)

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen Thank you very much for that link! Especially the "strong affiliation with the French monarchy" almost had me on the floor, laughing.